# Testing a method which modifies the field of the mocked class

Tags: java, junit, field, void, easymock

There are a lot of questions already asked but no real useful info for my particular case.

I want to test a method, which is in class A and its a void and it calls some methods from class B which then modifies or checks its fields - multiple ones.

Here is an example:

```
public class A {
private B b;

public A(B b){
    this.b = b;
}

public void checkStageOne(Worksheet ws){
    if( long statement){
        if(B.checkStorage(ws)){
            ws.setThing("Nasty");
        }
        else { ws.setStatus("Not so nasty"); }
    }
}
```

Lets say the LinkedLists are filled up somehow. The parameter of class A checkStageOne() is contained in a list in class B.

```
public class B {
private LinkedList<Worksheet> sheetList = new LinkedList<>();
private LinkedList<UsedParts> upList = new LinkedList<>();
private LinkedList<UsedParts> matList = new LinkedList<>();


public boolean checkStorage(int id){
     for(UsedParts up : upList){
        if(up.getSheetID()== id){
            for(Material mat : matList){
                if(up.getMatID() == mat.getMatID()){
                    if(mat.getQuantity() - up.getQuantityNeeded() < 0){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to mock class B but I have absolutely no idea how I could fake the fields of B and then even test the result on them. All I know is that I can test a void with EasyMock.expectLastCall(); but then I need to check if it really did with an assert.

Do you have any suggestions?

VBR,
assaultpig

Comment: you can create constructor for B that accepts 3 linkedLists, and then using mockito create for your test instance of B:
LinkedList mock1 = mock(LinkedList.class);
LinkedList mock2 = mock(LinkedList.class);
LinkedList mock3 = mock(LinkedList.class);
new B(mock1, mock2,mock3);
you can then check if there was an interaction with those mocks

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea. Do you know how to check that in EasyMock?

Answer (score 0):

To answer you comment, you do the same thing with EasyMock.

But I you want to mock B, then, that is not what you should do. Just mock `B`. Then, you only care about `checkStorage` returning `true` or `false` to test `A`.

Something like this:

```
B b = mock(B.class);
Worksheet ws = mock(Worksheet.class);
A a = new A(b);
expect(b.checkStorage()).andReturn(true); // expect one call to checkStorage to return true
ws.setThing("Nasty"); // expect setThing to be called

replay(b, ws);

a.checkStageOne(ws); // will call checkStorage that will return true

verify(b, ws); // will make sure setThing was called
```